# Anyway to connect sheets by script?

Tags: google-apps-script

According to the page on [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?vid=1-635797074220791385-3800122556), "In the new version of Google Sheets, spreadsheets must be explicitly granted permission to pull data from other spreadsheets using IMPORTRANGE.". I'm using apps script to automatically create sheets based on a template that contains a cell with IMPORTRANGE so do I have to manually go into each newly created sheet after it is created in the script to approve the connection between each sheet or is there a way to do this in apps script after it is created? Both sheets are owned by me but I guess this requirement to connect the sheets is not related to ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to connect them programmatically using importrange, you must manually connect them using the sheets interface.
alternatively, you could use scripts and timers directly to make it behave like importRange.